# Nestjs graphql upload error: POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs, apollo-server

I'm using NestJS 7 with graphql on node v14x
This is my graphql module configuration

```
import { Module, NestModule, RequestMethod, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';
import { graphqlUploadExpress } from "graphql-upload"
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { ApolloServerDataLoaderPlugin } from '@webundsoehne/nestjs-graphql-typeorm-dataloader';
import { GraphqlConfig } from './@core/config/config.interface';
import { getConnection } from 'typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const graphqlConfig = configService.get<GraphqlConfig>('graphql');
        return {
          buildSchemaOptions: {
            numberScalarMode: 'integer',
            plugins: [new ApolloServerDataLoaderPlugin({ typeormGetConnection: getConnection })]
          },

          sortSchema: graphqlConfig.sortSchema,
          autoSchemaFile:
            graphqlConfig.schemaDestination || './src/schema.graphql',
          debug: graphqlConfig.debug,
          path: graphqlConfig.endPoint,
          uploads: false,
          playground: graphqlConfig.playgroundEnabled,

          context: ({ req, connection }) => {
            if (connection) {
              return { req: { headers: connection.context } }
            }
            return { req }
          },
          installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
          dateScalarMode: "isoDate",
          subscriptions: {
            keepAlive: 5000
          }
        };
      },
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),

  ],

})
export class GQLModule implements NestModule {

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) { }

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    const graphqlConfig = this.configService.get<GraphqlConfig>('graphql');
    consumer.apply(graphqlUploadExpress()).forRoutes(graphqlConfig.endPoint)
  }

}
```

After getting stuck on file upload not working on node v14.x, I find this [issue comment](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/901#issuecomment-809157261). And I'm importing everything from `graphql-upload` on my resolver, But still getting error message like `POST body missing. Did you forget use body-parser middleware?`

Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

I have nearly identical configuration, and it works correctly for me. Since I use both REST and GraphQL, I have limited the route to 'graphql'

```
import { MiddlewareConsumer, Module, NestModule } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ServeStaticModule } from '@nestjs/serve-static';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { AuthorModule } from '../author/author.module';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { join } from 'path';
const {
  graphqlUploadExpress,
} = require('graphql-upload');

const isLocalEnvironment = () => process.env.ENV === 'local';

console.log('isLocal', isLocalEnvironment(), process.env.ENV);

const modules = [
  AuthorModule,
  
  GraphQLModule.forRoot({
    playground: isLocalEnvironment(),
    fieldResolverEnhancers: ['guards'],
    debug: isLocalEnvironment(),
    autoSchemaFile: isLocalEnvironment() ? 'schema.gql' : true,
    introspection: isLocalEnvironment(),
    useGlobalPrefix: true,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
  }),
  MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.COSMOSDB_CONNECTION_STRING, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    retryWrites: false,
    autoIndex: true,
  }),
  
];

@Module({
  imports: modules,
  providers: [ApiService],
})
export class APIModule implements NestModule{
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(graphqlUploadExpress({ maxFileSize: 10000000, maxFiles: 10 })).forRoutes('graphql');
  }
}
```

In my main.ts file, I bootstrap the application.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') require('dotenv').config();
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { APIModule } from './api/api.module';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
const prefix = "api/";
async function bootstrap() {
  const port = process.env.PORT;
  const app: INestApplication = await NestFactory.create(APIModule);
  
  app.enableCors();
  app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
  app.use(urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));
  // Because I use the global prefix of api/, I need to hit my service at /api/graphql
  app.setGlobalPrefix(prefix);
  console.log('Starting on port ' + port);
  await app.listen(port);
  return app;
}

bootstrap();
```

Since your configuration looks good to me, I'm guessing something went wrong in your bootstrap function, or that you aren't hitting the /graphql route.

I am using the latest version of NestJS which no longer includes a graphql upload implementation, so unlike you, I do not need to turn uploads off.